# Get raw “mobile data usage” data

Tags: adb, mobile-data, google-pixel

I’m in a bit of a feud with my mobile data provider and want to prove to them that I started using my mobile Internet after a specific time.

Currently, the default mobile data usage in android is not really useful as it does not even allow me to view data usage per day! I’m using a google pixel 6a.

Ideally I want to have mobile data usage data per second. Is it possible to extract that data out of my phone?

I have found some apps online, but at best they show data usage per day. I need more granularity.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to make do with what is available.